# Cron job is not running script.sh for the root user

Tags: shell, cron, centos, root

Cron job is not running `script.sh` present in `/var/www/html` for Centos root user, but it runs script present in `/root` folder. Can you please let me know the reason?

Comment: You do realize we can't login to your server and investigate this for you, right?  You need to provide at least *some* information.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Cron job is * * * * * sh /var/www/html/script.sh

Comment: This script is for taking DB dump. Checked Cron logs it is running command every minute but not creating dump file. If I run the scrip directly it is creating the dump file.

Comment: Do you have a log file for one of the runs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but imho you should check the following:

- Maybe the script needs some environment variables to be set by the time the script is run.  Try adding to your script the `.profile` file or alike for the user running the script - in this case, the root user.  That's probably under `/root/.profile`.
- If you don't have a log file being generated by the script, try to set it in your `crontab` like `* * * * * sh /var/www/html/script.sh > dump.log`.  However, if this script is supposed to do a dump of your DB, then maybe you don't want to run this every minute of the day... if your DB is big, then it may be a great overhead for it...
- And last, but not least - is the script really under `/var/www/html/script.sh`?  That's not a directory that you would want to use for DB dumps or alike.

I hope this helps - to be honest, not much can be done with the information you provided :-)